# MongoDB recursive query top parent object

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection of locations and want to retrieve a top parent location.
For example, if I query for location by id 4, location with id 1 should be returned.

```
{_id: "1", "parentLocationID": null, "childLocationIds": [2]}
{_id: "2", "parentLocationID": "1", "childLocationIds": [3]}
{_id: "3", "parentLocationID": "2", "childLocationIds": [4]}
{_id: "4", "parentLocationID": "3", "childLocationIds": []}
```

My current solution is to recursively query db from backend until *parentLocationID* is null.
What I'd like to do is move recursion processing to Mongo.
I found that Mongo supports recursive queries with [$graphLookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/graphLookup/), and this is how I started:

```
db.locations.aggregate([
    {
        "$match": {
            "childLocationIds": {"$elemMatch": {"$eq", "4"}}
        }
    },
    {
        "$graphLookup": {
            "from": "locations",
            "startWith: "$childLocationIds",
            "connectFromField": "childLocationIds",
            "connectToField": "childLocationIds",
            "as": "parentLocations"
        }
    }
])
```

Query only returns first level parent. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Is it possible to restructure the data? And , how frequently data is changed? Check this out: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-tree-structures-with-ancestors-array/ and https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-tree-structures-with-materialized-paths/

Comment: No, but thanks for the links! You gave me inspiration for solving this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution, a couple of more pipelines required:

```
db.locations.aggregate([
    {
        "$match": {
            "_id": "4"
        }
    },
    {
        "$graphLookup": {
            "from": "locations",
            "startWith: "$parentLocationID",
            "connectFromField": "_id",
            "connectToField": "parentLocationID",
            "as": "parentLocations"
        }
    },
    {
        "$unwind": "$parentLocations"
    },
    {
        "$replaceRoot": {
            "newRoot": "$parentLocations"
        }
    },
    {
        "$match": {
            "parentLocationID": null
        }
    }
])
```

*$match* will find location with id 4, then *$graphLookup* will append parent objects to *parentLocations* property. Remaining pipelines are used to extract top level location.